# Software Center stopped working suddenly... Unable to uninstall. Please help

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-center

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 and suddenly, Ubuntu Software Center stopped working. When I click on icon from launcher, it's blinking. When I try to open it from terminal with the command, 'sudo apt-get remove software-center', I'm getting the following error:

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fIN
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Please tell me how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to remove the problematic file .

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. I simply removed the problematic file. In my case, the file

```
dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fIN
```

was causing the problem. So, I removes it. Now it is working.